# Qt cmake project with included unit tests using Qt Test framework

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I want to setup a Qt project using CMake. My main project produces a dynamic library and for being able to conduct unit tests and a continuous integration i also want to have a subdirectory called "UnitTests" to hold my unit tests which using the Qt Test framework.

So the structure would look like this:

- MyLibraryProject

  - UnitTests

    - testcase_1.cpp
- MyClass.h
- MyClass.cpp
- CMakeLists.txt

(sorry for the bad visualization but i did not knew how to draw a tree in here)

Problems that i have to accomplish that is that Qt Creator seems not helping to set this up. And so i looked around if there might be something done different using Qt and Qt creator.

Answer (score 0):

I came to a working solution that i want to share with you.

Instead of following the suggestions to create a Qt Testproject you simply create a new folder called "UnitTests" in your mainproject. In my case this was MyLibraryProject. Then you add a new TestCase to your project and place it right into that new folder "UnitTests".

Next you need to reconfigure your CMakeLists file as follows:

```
project(MyLibraryProject LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Test)

add_library(MyLibraryProject SHARED
  # here you add your Sources for the main project
)

target_link_libraries(MyLibraryProject PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core)

# From here on we added things for the test project

enable_testing() # this is used to enable CTest if you want it.

# new executable for the tests
add_executable(UnitTests UnitTests/tst_ApiTest.cpp) 

# adding the test to CTest
add_test(NAME ApiTest COMMAND ApiTest)

# link your library to your test code
target_link_libraries(UnitTests PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Test MyLibraryProject)
```

So basically you edit your CMakeLists.txt file and create a new executable for Qt Test and then only you need to link against your library.

This has worked out for me and i even can use Qt Creator with it